# Firebase data is not updating after switching the wifi in android app

Tags: android, firebase

We are building an app, and in the app we count and store the number of times a user interacts/opens an app.
When the app comes to foreground we update the a counter on firebase.

We are facing an issue with Samsung Galaxy S4, when a user switches between WIFI networks while the app is running, from second network switch onwards no data gets updated on firebase. This issue is not observed on any other Android/iOs mobile devices.

Issue explanation:

Lets say there are two WIFI networks A and B

1. User connected to WIFI network A and opened the app. We increment a counter 'activity' in firebase. Say 'activity' value was 0 intially, now it becomes 1.
2. When the app goes to background mode and comes to foreground, we again increment the counter 'activity' on firebase, so 'activity' becomes 2. As long as the user is in WIFI network A. incrementing counter 'activity' works fine.
3. When the user connects to another WIFI network say B, and opens the app, counter 'activity' increment action gets triggered, but data is not stored on firebase. (Value of counter 'activity' on firebase remains 2)
4. Now when the user switches back to WIFI network A, and brings the app to foreground increment action increments the value twice, so counter 'activity' becomes 4. On firebase value jumped from 2 to 4, but while the user was on WIFI network B data was not updated, means reconnecting to network A is triggering the increment action twice, which is making the counter 'activity' value to 4.

Comment: I wrote up an answer how Firebase works when your network connection drops, which I think is the case here. If that doesn't address your question, can you provide some more concrete data points? E.g. the code that you run and some debug output would go a long way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Firebase Android client loses connectivity, it keeps a queue of any write operations. When it comes online again, it applies those write operations.

It looks in your case like Firebase is unable to establish a connection when you're on network B. So in your step 3, the write operations ends up being queued.

And then on step 4 it is applied on the server, after which the next write operation increments the `activity` value again.

Comment: Frank thanks. Please confirm my understanding using the following travel scenario. I am at airport A, my mobile app is using the airport's WiFi. I write something to the Firebase DB just as I lose my airport wifi connection. I take-off, fly, and land at airport B. I will never see my Firebase DB write from airport A until I return to airport A's wifi connection? Is there a command to force flush the FB write queue?